# Edit VFP9 Report Within My Application

Tags: visual-foxpro

I saw in an application that it will allow to edit VFP9 report within that application. I have searched a lot but cannot find the solution for this. Can anyone help me on this?

[image: Application which facilitates editing Report]

Above is the picture of the application that will allow to edit the report at runtime.

Please tell me how can I provide the ability to edit VFP9 report at runtime within my application to my end users.

Comment: You seem to have an issue with the Caps lock. It looks like it gets stuck every time you write a new word. You should fix this before posting.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually very simple. In VFP, Create Report and Modify Report command is available at run time.

Report files are tables. At runtime you could get a copy of an existing report and modify that one, or create one from scratch and modify that one. ie:

```
Use (_samples+'data\Customer')
Create Report mySampleReport ;
   from Customer Column ;
   fields Cust_id, Company, Contact
Modify Report mySampleReport
```

Comment: i have do that command, when i run that command it will successfully running in my project, but whenever i build an exe of that project it is not running

Comment: It always works successfully for me from within an exe.

Comment: Can you provide full code for that and if you can email me example project for that my email is star.mohsin@gmail.com